# Self annotation of inner class defined from outer

Tags: scala, types, self-type

First code

```
trait Service {
 def what: String
}

class ServiceImpl extends Service {
  def what = "ServiceImpl"
}
```

Now, let's say I want to define inner class with `self type annotation` but the type would be passed from outer class, like this:

```
class Foo[T <: Service] {
  class Bar {this: T => }
  val bar: Option[Bar] = Some(new Bar with T)
}
```

I would like to be able to call methods defined in `Service` trait within this Bar class. But defining it like that gives me an error:

```
<console>:10: error: class type required but T found
   val bar = new Bar with T
                          ^
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible cause `T` is an abstract type. But there are other ways to achieve this, like cake pattern.

Comment: @AlexIv - I don't think the cake pattern would help with generic mix-ins. You'd still end up having to make a separate version of the class for each possible value of `T`.

Comment: @DaoWen Not quite, you can write abstract version of Foo, and later "at the end" use the service you want/need, so no need to redefine class for each T. Although this is also depends on the use case, which is not clear to me.

Comment: There need to be concrete implementations of both `Foo` and `Bar` classes therefore `Foo` cannot be abstract.

Comment: @AlexIv - I don't think that can work. You can't use abstract types as mix-ins either. If you can come up with a working example then I'd like to see it, but like I said I'm pretty well convinced that it doesn't work.

Comment: @goral - You actually have another restriction here in that `Bar` must be a *trait*, but there's nothing in the type signature that restricts it from being a *class* type instead. I actually don't think there's a way to put that type of restriction on a type in Scala.

Comment: How is that? Why `Bar` must be a _trait_ ?

Comment: @goral - Sorry, that was a typo. I meant that `T` (not `Bar`) must be a trait-type, otherwise it can't be used with the `with` keyword.

Comment: @DaoWen I would definitely not choose such architecture, but i was talking about something similar to [this](https://gist.github.com/4lex1v/5df4bfd2fd100551f74d). Again i'm not clear on the goals author is trying to achieve, so ...